# Directive is being called only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I have created a custom directive that goes inside my input field. The purpose of this directive is to analyse the values/data inside the Inputfield. *`This directive is supposed to be called everytime the inputField is given focus/cursor.`*

However the problem is, my custom *directive is only being called once*. I am not sure why isn't it getting called every time the input field is focused.

What am I doing wrong here?

I am new to Angular so I am sure there is some important detail that I have missed somewhere.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dS259hzS24dnzkTOOgbz?p=preview).

Comment: don't link plunkr, use stack snippet or show code. this  question is unasable when the plunkr link won't be available anymore

Comment: @Walfrat Ok. Downvoter, make sure to state the reason for down votes as well so that the "supposed" mistake won't be repeated in the future!

Comment: that was the reason :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected behaviour, the link function is only called once for any given instance of a directive. Since you're interested in the `focus` event, I added an event listener to the element the directive is applied to:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("myapp", ['ngMaterial']);

mainApp.directive("myDirective", function($log) {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        require : "ngModel",
        scope   : {
            myDirective : "="
        },
        link    : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          element.on('focus', doSomething);

          function doSomething() {
            $log.log("value is:", scope.myDirective);
            if (ngModel.$isEmpty() && scope.myDirective && scope.myDirective.length > 0) {
               ngModel.$setUntouched();
               ngModel.$setValidity();
            }
        }

      }
    }
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RwTSsQKBtzzJDXE8by1I?p=preview)

Since you also mentioned 'cursor', you might be interested in the `mouseover` event as well. It's as simple as adding another event listener:

`element.on('mouseover', doSomething)`

Note: I added an additional check for `scope.myDirective` to avoid the console errors on reading `length` of `undefined`.

At OP's request:

I don't know if jqLite supports all of these, but for a list of all DOM events you should check this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events), you're probably most interested in the focus-, keyboard- & mouse events.

For a list of all jqLite functions check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite)

Comment: Perfect! Can you please link me to the list of functions that "element" object can use? Can you also link me to the list of events like 'focus'/'mouse over'?

Comment: @UmerFarooq I added the relevant link in my post

Comment: @UmerFarooq I missed it before but I also added a link to all jqLite functions